# Extracting an object from JSON in a 'parent' object's .fromJson method

Tags: json, object, flutter, dart

I want to store a ColorSwatch in json, and extract it in an object's .fromJson method.

I've tried storing it in JSON as:

```
"colorSwatch": "ColorSwatch(0xFFFFB7DE, { 'highlight': Color(0xFFFFB7DE), 'splash': Color(0xFFF94CBF) })"
```

Then extracting it with:

colorSwatch = jsonMap['colorSwatch'],

It didn't work.  I tried changing the JSON to:

```
"colorSwatch": "0xFFFFB7DE, { 'highlight': Color(0xFFFFB7DE), 'splash': Color(0xFFF94CBF) }"
```

Then modifying the object's .fromJson method to:

```
colorSwatch = ColorSwatch(jsonMap['colorSwatch']),
```

It didn't work.  I then tried:

```
colorSwatch = jsonMap['colorSwatch'] as ColorSwatch,
```

Didn't work.

I then tried saving the highlight and splash colours in json separately and extracting with

```
highlight = jsonMap['highlight'] as int,
splash = jsonMap['splash'] as int,
colorSwatch = new ColorSwatch(0xFFFFD28E, {'highlight': Color(highlight), 'splash': Color(splash)}),
```

But aparently I'm only allowed to do operations on static variables in an object's fromJson method.

So I'm stuck.

I want the ColorSwatch object attached to the Riddle object, so all the properties associated with a Riddle are in one place and don't need to be assembled elsewhere when needed.

- It doesn't seem possible to build an Object, here ColorSwatch, inside
  another objects .fromJson method, is this correct?
- So that means I    have to extract the entire object in a single line
  of code, how do I    do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json doesn't support hexadecimals so you need to write them as a string and convert them using `int.tryparse`:

```
  var hexadecimalString = 'ff542144';
  var decimalInteger = int.tryParse(hexadecimalString, radix: 16);
```

for your `ColorSwatch` you need a helper class like this:

```
class ColorSwatch {
  final Color swatch;
  final Color splash;
  final Color highlight;

  ColorSwatch(this.swatch, this.splash, this.highlight);

  factory ColorSwatch.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return ColorSwatch(
      Color(int.tryParse(json['colorSwatch'], radix: 16)),
      Color(int.tryParse(json['highlight'], radix: 16)),
      Color(int.tryParse(json['splash'], radix: 16)),
    );
  }

  String toJson() {
    return jsonEncode({
      'colorSwatch': swatch.value.toRadixString(16),
      'highlight': highlight.value.toRadixString(16),
      'splash': splash.value.toRadixString(16),
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Aligator, that's was a helpful answer.  In the end I:
1. saved the hexadecimal color values individually to JSON, 
2. extracted them using Color(int.parse(json['highlight'], radix 16));

The hexadecimal conversion solved it for me, I owe you for that.
Cheers
Sam.